# Rounding off negative decimal and positive decimal number

Tags: awk, sed, cut, head

I would like to round off the below numbers to nearest wholenumber using awk command and copy it to another column say col11 and col12. can anyone help

eg 1)

```
column5,column6,,,,,column11,column12,
     -21733.3, -4129.327,,,,,,,
```

output expected

```
 column5,column6,,,,,column11,column12,
-21733.3, -4129.327,,,,,-21733,-4129,
```

2. 

```
column5,column6,,,,,column11,column12,
      21733.3,4129.327,,,,,,,
```

output expected

```
 column5,column6,,,,,column11,column12,
21733.3,4129.327,,,,,21733,4129,
```

Comment: Should `.5` round up, or round down, or round to the nearest even number ("unbiased" rounding) or does it not matter? See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Round-Function.

Comment: @EdMorton or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding for even more ways one might want to round halves. In any case, I agree, adding some 1.9, -1.9, 1.5, -1.5, 2.5, -2.5, 15e-1, 0x1p-2, inf, nan... to the sample and corresponding expected output would have helped.

Answer (score 5):

If it's a simple CSV with no string field containing newlines or `,`s within quotes, then that could be done in `awk` with:

```bash
awk -F, -v OFS=, '
  NR > 1 {
    $11 = sprintf("%.0f", $5)
    $12 = sprintf("%.0f", $6)
  }
  {print}' < your-file
```

(`NR > 1` to apply it only to records starting with the second, not on the header line)

`sprintf("%.0f")` rounds to nearest, `int()` truncates the fractional part.

With `mlr`, using the column names and handling more complex CSVs (beware there are many variants of CSV formats though)

```bash
mlr --csv put '$column11 = round(float(strip($column5)));
               $column12 = round(float(strip($column6)))' < your-file
```

Numbers with surrounding whitespace are considered as *string* by `mlr`, hence the `strip`ping which yields another *string* without those spaces, which can then be converted to *float*, and that *float* passed to  `round()`.

If there was no whitespace around your numbers, this should be enough:

```bash
mlr --csv put '$column11 = round($column5);
               $column12 = round($column6)' < your-file
```

Comment: `sprintf("%.0f")` rounds `.5` to the nearest **even** number on many, but not all, systems so `1.5` would round to `2` but `2.5` would also round to `2` - just worth mentioning in case anyone thinks that `.5` would always round up or down or that `2.5` would round to `3` (or `2`) on all systems. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Round-Function.

Comment: @EdMorton This is called "banker's rounding" and is common in most languages.